What to use as a door for a height of only 6' high?
We have a weird area that doesn't require a normal door height, kind of a custom made space. What can we use as an interior door for the 6' height? Width can be normal 2'-3' wide.

For six feet, will need an older type solid wood door cut down, or make your own door to size.  Most interior doors are made with just small size wood on the outside edges and a piece in the centre and two skins to cover.

Many doors still exist that are less than 6ft... Ducking one's head entering many castles is an easily learnt skill after forgetting once.

A picture of a duck over short doors helps.

@crip659 seen a carved message in stone: "Duck or Grouse"...

This sounds like storage rather than a room.  I've used 6' wardrobe doors in the past for walk-in storage (narrow double doors in one case)

An ordinary plain hollow door can be trimmed using a circular saw, and the off-cut top rail can then be skinned and reinserted and glued into the open cavity.
A patterned hollow door will probably need to be cut back at both ends to look balanced. but that can be done fairly easily too.
You will need circular saw*, straight-edge guide, clamps, wood glue, chisel, tape measure.
(*) A track saw or panel saw are better, but a regular $25 circular saw can do the job.

Yep, I've done that before.

Thanks, I've also done this before but wanted to see if there was anything else out there or what other people have used.

Habitat for Humanity in my area has retail outlets called "ReStore". The sell used building supplies. You can likely find a six-panel pine door that you can resize with just a circular saw. The big box stores sell similar doors for under $200 so I would expect a big discount on a used one. An additional plus of used is the money spent on it goes to a good cause.

I’d be cautious about trying to take 8” off a paneled door… those rails are intrinsic to the structure. Much better would be a solid core (ie, particle board and skin) or a hollow slab.
